# How to dequeue a script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wp-enqueue-script

Wordpress has `wp_enqueue_script()` but not a `wp_dequeue_script()` function, so what would be the best way to dequeue a script? I'm using [LAB.js](http://labjs.com/) to load all of my scripts rather than enqueueing them server side, so I don't want plugins running around adding jQuery 10 times when I'm already loading it.

Would using `wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' )` accomplish the same purpose?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a `dequeue` method available ... I'm just not sure why it isn't wrapped in a `wp_dequeue_script()` method.  (I might create a ticket for this issue, actually)

But yes, using `wp_deregister_script` will accomplish what you're trying to do.  Just remember, if you ever *do* want to use WP's built-in jQuery later you'll need to re-queue it first.

Comment: If anyone's keeping score, the Trac ticket is here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14815

Comment: **Update**: The function `wp_dequeue_script()` will be included in the next release of WordPress.  To "un-enqueue" a script like jQuery, you'd just call `wp_dequeue_script('jquery')`.  This is changeset 15601: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/15601

Answer (score 4):

Since WordPress 3.1 there is actually a `wp_dequeue_script()` function available.

Comment: That function exists because of this question :)

Comment: Cool, just used it today :)