# Adding custom css to a wordpress plugin?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [best way to overide plugin CSS?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2680/best-way-to-overide-plugin-css)

Now and again I would come across a great wordpress plugin with it's own css style sheet.  I could edit the css in the plugin folder and it would work like a charm but if there was ever an update for the plugin, it would overwrite my custom css that I applied to it.

I know that I can target the class of the plugin in my own css and applying !important; to the end of the css style.  I've read though that this isn't good practice.

Is adding !important to the end of a css style bad practice and if so, what is the best way of targeting custom css of a wordpress plugin?

Thanks
Tyler

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it the way you are doing it now, or you can use the rule of greater specificity (ex `div.foo > ul#bar > li.baz` is more specific than just `#bar > .baz`).

P.S. I am not sure this is WordPress-specific.

Comment: The CSS part of the question itself certainly isn't WordPress-specific; however, the question of how to override Plugin-defined CSS rules *is* WordPress-specific. It seems, though, that this question has already been asked elsewhere on WPSE.