# How do I cleanly override a plugin's CSS with a child theme?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, css, child-theme

I have taken it upon myself to adhere to WordPress conventions so I can have a clean, sexy child theme. However, I am unsure how to proceed on a certain issue.

I would like to override the CSS for some plugins in my WordPress website, and [this wonderful post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2680/best-way-to-overide-plugin-css) was a great step in the right direction. My only concern is that I would like to do everything I can to **avoid overriding** the `header.php` file in my parent theme in order the do this.

Is there another wonderful way to do this? Thanks for your help!

**Update**:

As was pointed out by another user's comment, this is in fact dependent on how the plugin implements its styles. This aside, assume that the plugins do provide a way for styles to be implemented in the `style.css` sheet of the child theme, or, in my case, a separate `styles` folder linked to that `style.css` sheet.

I also know I can use `!important` all over the place, but this is generally frowned upon.

Comment: it depends entirely on how the plugins in question are adding their styles.

Comment: I updated my post to accomodate your comment. Thanks!

Comment: Close-voted as **not constructive**. Please edit your question to refer to **specific Plugins**, and include the **specific CSS implementation code** for those Plugins.

Comment: I would love to, but unfortunately this is a **pretty general question**. My goal is to **encapsulate all stylesheets** that add custom edits to **any plugin's styling** in a **single folder** in my child theme. This keeps some really clean code, and is very efficient. I will add specific, code, though!

Comment: I just found this [Simple Custom CSS](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/) plugin It handles everything discussed for enqueuing dependent CSS. Simple to install and use.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the plugins are correctly adding their styles via `wp_enqueue_style`, you simply need to dequeue them:

```
function wpa_dequeue_style() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'plugin-style-handle' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa_dequeue_style', 100 );
```

Whether or not this works depends on how and where the plugins are adding their styles, so there's no absolute answer without knowing specific methods the plugins in question use.

EDIT- another option that doesn't involve removing the styles entirely is to enqueue your own styles with the plugin styles as a dependency:

```
wp_enqueue_style(
    'my-styles',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/mystyles.css',
    array('plugin-style-handle')
);
```

Comment: This is certainly a step in the right direction. However, my overrides are edits, so the trade-off of copy-pasting the entire stylesheet and editing it is a bit counter-productive. Like you said, it's also entirely dependent on how the css is added.

Comment: see edit above.

Comment: I'll give that edit a shot. That looks like a great idea!

Comment: Wow, I can't upvote enough. It worked!

Comment: It's an old answer but helped me in 2020. Thanks!