# Editing a plugins element.style

Tags: plugins

I have recently added a plugin called better image credits.
I have used inspect element on my site to view the coding and have played around with it to get it the way i want it to look.
The trouble I am having is when editing the code it is element.style
And I have no idea how to properly edit this on the back end.

Does anyone know How i can do this please

Comment: Do you mean you want to add new stylesheet class definitions that your plugin will use, or that you want to control the HTML (including `style` attributes) that your plugin generates when it renders itself?

Comment: You can find both of these in the plugin folder in style.css and script.js (which dynamically generates the credits-container). Ideally you'd make a new fixed copy of the stylesheet and then override it ([solution in this old question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101037/how-do-i-cleanly-override-a-plugins-css-with-a-child-theme)) as you'll lose any in-place edits you make when you update the plugin, but if you're careful you can get away with that for now.

Comment: Hi Rup!

Thanks for your reply. It's all a little mind boggling for me but I am trying to learn.
So once I inspect element I see these two things and want them to look like the two things on the right https://postimg.org/image/6fj1nc1sl/

I think the first one with 640px changes depending on size of image but it aligns the credit to the right. If i remove it, it aligns it to the left which is what i want

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean by element.style. In that case I think you will have to edit the plugin code, alas: look in script.js in the plugin folder for the lines that starts `width:` and remove it, and either remove the `marginBottom:` line or change the value to 0. To remove the padding you can edit style.css also in the plugin folder. (As above these will get lost if you auto-update the plugin, though, so you'll now either need to be careful not to, or rename the plugin to 'camputer-better-credits' or something so it won't auto-update.)

Comment: Hi Rup!
Here is the script.js folder https://postimg.org/image/q0ezikvrf/
I removed the line starting with width but it didn't change anything.
I also did the changes in the style.css and it didn't change anything either

Comment: Really? I'm stuck then, sorry. I can't see where else they're coming from.