# wp_enqueue_style specifics for overwriting plugin styles

Tags: plugins, css, wp-enqueue-style

I'm trying to add some custom CSS to dictate a very small part of a plugin's look. I don't want to dequeue the whole think (I don't think) as I'm happy with the rest of it.

I found this answer here which would appear to be exactly what I need: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101038/118037

However I'm new to WP and I have not even the faintest idea of where I would put that second lot of code.

```
wp_enqueue_style(
    'my-styles',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/mystyles.css',
    array('plugin-style-handle')
);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you can put this code in your current active theme `function.php` file. more info for check this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Comment: It was giving me parse errors when I tried that before, though?

Comment: Please try my Answer code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your current active theme **function.php** file.

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('my-styles',get_template_directory_uri() . '/mystyles.css',array('plugin-style-handle'));
    }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```